# Boot into rescue mode in systemd

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, kde

After I installed KDE Plasma, I used `systemctl enable sddm-session`, and after reboot I found a black screen and I can't do anything.

Is there any way to boot into the command line? I can't disable ssdm-session

Next time I better use `ssdm --test-mode`?

Comment: Add `systemd.unit=rescue` to the [kernel options](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters)...

Comment: can you explain in more detail? btw i'm using grub

Comment: Did you read the wiki page I linked to? It includes specific information for Grub (and all the other boot{loaders,managers}.

Comment: got it! just using 'e' command in grub and add after 'linux' command! thx!

Answer (score 2):

Use a TTY terminal.  Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> and login, and disable the service.

Comment: it doesn't work, I also try 'ctrl+alt+f3' and other, it just go straight to black screen